# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc-guard’

Tags: firefox, gcc, address-sanitizer, fuzzing

During build of Firefox (older versions including 56.0, 57.0), I encountered the following error a lot of times:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc-guard’; did you mean ‘-fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc’?
```

no matter in an ASAN build or normal debug build.

With normal debug, I used following options:

```
ac_add_options --disable-jemalloc
ac_add_options --enable-crashreporter
ac_add_options --disable-elf-hack
export MOZ_DEBUG_SYMBOLS=1
ac_add_options --enable-debug-symbols
ac_add_options --disable-install-strip
ac_add_options --disable-strip
ac_add_options --disable-optimize
ac_add_options --enable-debug
ac_add_options --disable-profiling
ac_add_options --enable-fuzzing
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the option **--enable-fuzzing**, but no idea why and how to fix.

PS: I have g++, gcc version 7.4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC does not support sanitizer coverage but you can use clang instead:

```
apt-get install clang
# or, to force a specific version of clang:
apt-get install clang-8
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
# or, force a specific version of clang:
export CC=clang-8
export CXX=clang++-8
```

Comment: Hi. I added CC and CXX variables as you suggested and built Firefox 56.0. It was successful but I noticed that when Address sanitizer finds a bug and reports its stack trace, it does not give symbols anymore.

Comment: @CloverYe Try using [llvm-symbolizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#symbolizing-the-reports)